# Save the log in electron devtools to a file

Tags: javascript, logging, electron, angular5

I am working on Electron app with angular 5 for the rendering process,
is there is a way to export the console programmatically?

I need a way to synchronize the logging data to file so, I can review it anytime
without opening electron devtools and save as option, I need it programmatically

I save my own logs, but what if there is a module that logging an error i need to get whole console log history and export it to log file

Comment: I am using electron-log for my own logs and it works fine, but what if there is an error from a plugin or module that I use, I need a way to grab all the console log

Answer (score 5):

You can use **[electron-log](https://github.com/megahertz/electron-log)**, which is a logging module for Electron application. It can be used without Electron.
And you should use **[ngx-electron](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron)**.

---

Firstly, install `electron-log`

```
npm install electron-log
```

Require it in the electron's main process.

```
const logger = require('electron-log');
```

---

Then install `ngx-electron`

```
npm install ngx-electron
```

`ngx-electron` is exposing a module called `NgxElectronModule` which needs to be imported in your `AppModule`.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgxElectronModule} from 'ngx-electron';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      NgxElectronModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Once the module has been imported, you can easily use angular DI to ask for `ElectronService`.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ElectronService} from 'ngx-electron';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    logger

    constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) { 
        // this should be in init()
        if(this._electronService.isElectronApp) {
            this.logger = this._electronService.remote.require("electron-log");
        }
    }

    public testLogger() {
        this.logger.info('this is a message from angular');
    }
}
```

After that, you should be able to use `electron-log` in your components, just remember `import {ElectronService} from 'ngx-electron';`, and `this.logger = this._electronService.remote.require("electron-log");` in the components.