# Using winston logger with electron+angular 2

Tags: angular, logging, electron, winston

I'm trying to use winston logger inside and electron app hosting an angular 2 app and I just can't make it work.
The angular app is written in typescript.
Someone has a working example?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **[electron-log](https://github.com/megahertz/electron-log)**, it could output the log in the terminal and log file.

And to work with angular, you need **[ngx-electron](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron)**. By `remote.require("electron-log")` in your components.

Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988829/save-the-log-in-electron-devtools-to-a-file/50731755#50731755) of how to do it.